# regex и grep: вывести строки только содержащие 1 или 2 цифры

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, grep

Есть файл вида:

```
1 526 040
3685 / 17.10.2015 17:56
23
12
19
5
2
1 399 005
3684 / 17.10.2015 14:56
17
16
18
14
34
1 209 945
```

Мне нужно вывести строки содержащие только одно число из одной цифры или двух, и отбросить строки содержащие что либо еще, напр мне нужен такой результат

```
23
12
19
5
2
```

Пробовал так не получилось cat /media/sda5/books/Программирование/test/5x36 | grep '^([1-9])'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat test | grep -P "^\d\d?$"
```

Это для современного grep, поддерживающего ключ `-P` по которому он начинает понимать PCRE регулярные выражения.

POSIX совместимое регулярное выражение для любого grep выглядит так:

```
cat test | grep "^[0-9][0-9]\?$"
```

Answer (score 2):

awk король текстовых файлов

```
awk '/^[0-9]{1,2}$/' text.txt
```

Comment: Про awk соглашусь, но спрашивавший упомянул именно grep.

Comment: grep "^\s*[0-9]\{1,2\}\s*$" test